# Swift: Getting type(of:) to return the name of my typealias instead of the final type

Tags: swift

Is there anyway to get the below to return "MyStringType" instead of "String"

```
typealias MyStringType = String

let myVar: MyStringType = "Some string"
let result = type(of: myVar)
print(result) //this prints out String, but I would prefer to get MyStringType.
```

Comment: A typealias is just a synonym, it doesn't change the type

Comment: Agreed. I'm just wondering if there's any way to get the synonym instead of the type.

Comment: @MAH `typealias`es are evaluated through during compilation, and there’s no trace left anywhere that you called the type anything but, e.g., `String`. Can you give a bit more info on why you need the above to print `MyStringType`?

Comment: Note that the how types are converted to strings isn't a promised interface, so even if this worked, you couldn't rely on it. Is this just for logging/debugging purposes, or are you trying to rely on the string-value of types for logic purposes?

Comment: Trying to rely on string value to generate HTML forms from structs using `Mirror(reflecting:)`. It seems the consensus is that it's not going to work. Just thought I'd try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. And it doesn't matter if it's something you defined.

```swift
"\(MyStringType.self)" // "String"
"\([String: String].Element.self)" // "(key: String, value: String)"
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/element